# How to config uWSGI path for Django project?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I'm working on [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to setup uWSGI but I'm stuck by this command:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/user/Env/firstsite --chdir /home/user/firstsite -w firstsite.wsgi
```

first of all, my actual directory path in /home/ubuntu/Es2al2/website, "website": is a project which I work on.

I have no idea what is that command does exactly also, I place my virtual environment into the project itself like so: /home/ubuntu/Es2al2/website/venv/ so, how can I show virtual environment for uWSGI, have I should place my venv like he does by outside the main project or may I place my own venv as I typed in my path?

**Note:**

"firstsite" is the project that tutorial has created and you can substitute by my real project "website" instead, as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make same exact structure. Just declare your own setup:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --home <virtual-env-path> --chdir <django-project-path> -w <django-project-name>.wsgi
```

So you can go with:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/ubuntu/Es2al2/website/venv --chdir /home/ubuntu/Es2al2/website -w website.wsgi
```

You can check each option description and how to use it from official doc here: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html